Proving or disproving an inequality
For positive parameters $a,b,c$ and for integer $n$ let
$$g(n)=\sum_{k=2}^n a^{k-2}h(k,n)$$
$$h(k,n)=\prod_{j=k}^{n-1}(b+(j-1)c)$$
With the convention that the sum over a empty set is 0 and the product over a empty set is 1.
I want to see if for any $s<N$, $g(N)-a^{N-s}g(s)$ is always non negative or not. I have tried for different parameter values and have always got positive value. However, I am unable to prove it. I have tried grouping together terms with same powers of $a$ but that didn't help. Can anyone help in proving this or give a counter-example.

Does brackets in the definition of $h$ mean the integer part of a number?

No, sorry for the confusion

Python shows that it's true for integer $a,b,c,N,s \in {1,2, \ldots, 20}$.

Do you mean its not true above that or you didn't check?

Now I checked it. The answer is below.

Let us show that $g(N) \ge a^{N-s} g(s)$. Put $h_{k,n} = h(k,n)$ for more short notation. It's sufficient to show that $a^2 g(N) \ge a^{N-s} a^2 g(s)$, i.e.
$$ \sum_{k=2}^N a^k h_{k,N} \ge a^{N-s} \sum_{k=2}^s a^k h_{k,s} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$ \sum_{k=2}^N a^k h_{k,N} \ge \sum_{k=2}^s a^{N-s+k} h_{k,s} \quad (*).$$
In $(*)$ we have:
coefficient with $a^N$ equals to $h_{N,N}$ in L.H.S. and $h_{s,s}$ in R.H.S.
coefficient with $a^{N-1}$ equals to $h_{N-1,N}$ in L.H.S. and $h_{s-1,s}$ in
R.H.S.
coefficient with $a^{N-2}$ equals to $h_{N-2,N}$ in L.H.S. and $h_{s-2,s}$ in R.H.S.
And so on. Moreover, there is bigger amount of summands in L.H.S.
Now it's sufficient to prove that

$h_{N,N} \ge h_{s,s}$
$h_{N-1,N} \ge h_{s-1,s}$
$h_{N-2,N} \ge h_{s-2,s}$

And so on. In other words, we want to show that $h_{N-i,N} \ge h_{s-i,s}$. It's very easy. Indeed,
$$ h_{N-i,N} = \prod_{N-i}^{N-1}(b+(j-1)c) \ge   \prod_{s-i}^{s-1}(b+(j-1)c) = h_{s-i,s} \quad (**)$$
because first multiplier in L.H.S. of $(**)$ is not less than the first multiplier in R.H.S. of $(**)$,  second multiplier in L.H.S. of (**) is not less than the second multiplier in R.H.S. of $(**)$ and so on. Q.e.d.
